# Consuming restapi and store Json response to different tables in Springboot JPA?

Tags: java, json, jpa

I am new to Spring boot and these JSON objects. I have a requirement where I need to invoke GET RestAPI and it returns list of nested Json Objects. I need some particular fields from Json object and store it into Database(SQL Server-backend) tables.
And these tables having relationship between them,also my Entity class and these Json structure not same. below is my code,
Json response:

```
[
  {
    "ApplicationName": "ACD tool",
    "city": "Europe",
    "IsActive": "true",
    "AppOwner": "Ragavendr raj",
    "AppTeamMember": "Siyan",
    "CreatedBy": "pav",
    "AppDetails": {
      "Language": "VB.net",
      "Version": "2.0"
    }
  },
  {
    "ApplicationName": "QR check",
    "city": "US",
    "IsActive": "true",
    "AppOwner": "Amar",
    "AppTeamMember": "miyas",
    "CreatedBy": "rosh",
    "AppDetails": {
      "Language": "c#",
      "Version": "2.0"
    }
  }
]
```

Table entities:
Application Entity:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="APPLICATION")
public class Application implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="APPLICATION_ID")
    private long applicatioId;
    
    @Column(name="APPLICATION_NAME")
    private String applicationName;
    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="application")
    private List<ApplicationUserRoleMap> applicationUserRoleMap;
    
    @Column(name="CREATED_BY")
    private String createdBy;
    
    @Column(name="CREATED_ON")
    private String createdOn;
    
    @Column(name="MODIFIED_BY")
    private String modifiedBy;
    
    @Column(name="MODIFIED_ON")
    private String modifiedOn;
    
    @Column(name="DELETE_FLG")
    private String deleteFlg;
    
    @Column(name="DISPLAY_FLG")
    private String displayFlg;
    
    //getters and setters


}
```

User Entity:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="USER")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    private long userId;
    
    @Column(name="USER_NAME")
    private String userName;
    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="user")
    private List<ApplicationUserRoleMap> applicationUserRoleMap;

    @Column(name="CREATED_BY")
    private String createdBy;
    
    @Column(name="CREATED_ON")
    private String createdOn;
    
    @Column(name="MODIFIED_BY")
    private String modifiedBy;
    
    @Column(name="MODIFIED_ON")
    private String modifiedOn;
    
    @Column(name="DELETE_FLG")
    private String deleteFlg;
    
    @Column(name="DISPLAY_FLG")
    private String displayFlg;
    
    //getters and setters
    
    
}
```

Role Entity:

```
   @Entity
@Table(name="ROLE")
public class Role implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ROLE_ID")
    private long roleId;
    
    @Column(name="ROLE_NAME")
    private String roleName;
    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="role")
    private List<ApplicationUserRoleMap> applicationUserRoleMap;

    @Column(name="CREATED_BY")
    private String createdBy;
    
    @Column(name="CREATED_ON")
    private String createdOn;
    
    @Column(name="MODIFIED_BY")
    private String modifiedBy;
    
    @Column(name="MODIFIED_ON")
    private String modifiedOn;
    
    @Column(name="DELETE_FLG")
    private String deleteFlg;
    
    @Column(name="DISPLAY_FLG")
    private String displayFlg;
    
    //getters and setters
}
```

ApplicationUserRoleMap entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="APPLICATION_USER_ROLE_MAP")
public class ApplicationUserRoleMap implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="APPLICATION_USER_ROLE_MAP_ID")
    private long applicatioUserRoleMapId;
    
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="APPLICATION_ID")
    private List<Application> application;
    
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
    private List<User> user;
    
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID")
    private List<Role> role;

    @Column(name="CREATED_BY")
    private String createdBy;
    
    @Column(name="CREATED_ON")
    private String createdOn;
    
    @Column(name="MODIFIED_BY")
    private String modifiedBy;
    
    @Column(name="MODIFIED_ON")
    private String modifiedOn;
    
    @Column(name="DELETE_FLG")
    private String deleteFlg;
    
    @Column(name="DISPLAY_FLG")
    private String displayFlg;
    
    //getters and setters
    

}
```

From json object fields AppOwner and AppTeamMember should added to roles table and their corresponding name added to user table, role-user-appliication ids mapping added to map table.

Can someone suggest me the best way to achieve this...Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at any guides online and run into a problem they didn’t help with? Or look on GitHub for any projects which do this (I’m sure there will be thousands)? Those would be your best way to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a DTO and using Jackson or Google GSON deserialize this JSON to this object and after this re-map to domain model.

Also there is a possibility to use only Google GSON to convert this JSON to JsonObject and by doing this no need for Java objects.

However, your entity has more fields that are required to be populated. I guess per requirements you get a full dataset during the application runtime and perform an enrichment from external system by GET request.

Keep answer short - investigate where you can get all data for your entities and after this enrich from REST response.

Answer (score 0):

you can use GSON to convert json to object and make entity class then u can access field u want
GSON is an open-source Java library which is used to serialize and deserialize Java objects to JSON.
u can follow this link for more details

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-json-string-to-java-object-using-gson/